# Can a kiwano melon become alcohol?

Tags: wine, fermentation

Could someone make wine (or any other alcoholic beverage) from [kiwano melons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumis_metuliferus) aka horned melons? Like, if you needed to make alcohol and the only prominent fruit is kiwano, could you make it work? In any case, it'd probably be a good idea, it tastes like banana and kiwi

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can make alcohol from anything that contains sugar, so...

Yes, of course you can make alcohol from kiwano melon, using the same technique as with any melon (or in fact most fruit) - get the juice from it and use your normal moonshine technique :-)